# Adaptive bitrate ingest(publishing) for live stream

Tags: youtube-api, live-streaming, twitch, encoder, youtube-livestreaming-api

As I know by doing some research,
popular CDN based live streaming platform(e.g, **twitch.tv, youtube live**) provides
**recommended encoder settings**(resolution, bitrate, fps) for broadcasters
who use advanced software encoder (e.g, obs, xsplit).
Before doing live stream, broadcaster should test one's upload bandwidth 
and select one of the recommendations. And once the encoder setting is selected, it can't be changed during live stream.

On the delivery side however, there is popular **adaptive bitrate streaming**(DASH, HLS) to cope with heterogeneous bandwidth state of the viewers.

```
[CDN based live streaming architecture]

<--------------Ingest Side------------------->    <------Delivery Side--->          
                    RTMP                                 HLS
[Broadcaster] ----------------> [Media Server]--->[CDN]--------> viewer 1
              constant bitrate                           | 720p
                                                   ABR   |-----> viewer 2
                                                         | 360p
                                                         |-----> viewer 3
                                                           240p
```

My question is,
**why live streaming platform, like twitch, youtube live, does not provide any bitrate adaptation during ingest to media server?

Or do they have bitrate control only on their mobile apps?**
In my opinion, adaptviely changing bitrate according to publisher's bandwidth seems necessary and reasonable in case of bad network or bandwidth fluctuations.

**Is there any bitrate adaptation for live ingesting side that I don't know of?**
I know that realtime video systems(e.g, webRTC, Hangouts) has their control logic to deal with congestion and packet loss.
Therefore, I assume that mobile streaming apps for youtube live, twitch.tv have their own bitrate control logic as well.
However, I couldn't find any docs or information about it and also couldn't find any, for the case where broadcasters use advanced encoder to do better live streaming.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any bitrate adaptation for live ingesting side that I don't know of?

Yes. Many encoders (including OBS) let you change the bitrate on the fly. It just doesn’t do it automatically.

> why live streaming platform, like twitch, youtube live, does not provide any bitrate adaptation during ingest to media server?

Because nobody at those companies have done the work to make it work. Those companies don’t put a lot of value on broadcasters who supply a bad experience to viewers, and would rather put the engineering effort into people with stable connections and high quality input.